# hackerrank solution in c for "Array Manipulation"

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm

```c
long arrayManipulation(int n, int queries_rows, int queries_columns, int** queries)
{
    long num, a, b, maxnum = INT_MIN;
    long* arrptr = calloc(n, sizeof(long));
    for(int i = 0;i<(queries_rows);i++)
    {
      num = queries[i][2];
      if(num==0)
      {
          continue;
      }
      printf("%ld ", num);
      a = queries[i][0];
      b = queries[i][1];
      for(long i = a-1;i<b;i++)
      {
        arrptr[i] += num;
        if(maxnum<(arrptr[i]))
        {
            maxnum = arrptr[i];
        }
      }
  }
  free(arrptr);
  return maxnum;
}
```

I have to optimize this program so that it can be executed in less time can you help??

this program is supposed to initialize an array of a size n(function argument) with 0(lets call array arr)
then there will be query in form
`a b k`
`1 2 3`
`4 5 6`

and then in array arr we have add k between the limits a and b
and then return max of arr

example
Sample Input

5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100

Sample Output

200

Explanation

After the first update list will be 100 100 0 0 0.
After the second update list will be 100 200 100 100 100.
After the third update list will be 100 200 200 200 100.
The returned answer will be 200.

Comment: @4386427 I corrected it and now only problem is I have to reduce time that error at int* arrptr was just a typing mistake, thanks

Comment: Do yourself (and everybody reading your code) a favor and use array indexing when using values through pointers, eg: `num = *(*(queries+i)+2);` is equivalent to `num = queries[i][2];`

Comment: @pmg can we use pointers of array like that??              Sorry for asking such a dummy questions though.

Comment: Yes, you can use pointers like that. The compiled code will, very probably, be equal whatever syntax you use. You may like to read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Probably not the reason for "Time Limit Exceeded", but can you do the updates directly from input without putting everything in an array (keep just the data array)?

Comment: ok i'll do that wait a minute please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218564/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-pmg).

Comment: Any solutions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have been working on it I found a good and understandable code on it with O(n) approach, it works well under required time and it doesn't have errors.

```c
long arrayManipulation(int n, int queries_rows, int queries_columns, int** queries) 
{
  long num, a, b, maxnum = INT_MIN;
  int* arrptr = calloc(n, sizeof(long));
  for(int i=0;i<queries_rows;i++)
  {
   arrptr[queries[i][0] -1] +=queries[i][2];
   arrptr[queries[i][1]] -= queries[i][2];
  }
   long count = 0; 
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   count += arrptr[i];
   arrptr[i]=count;
      if(count>maxnum) maxnum=count;
  }
       printf("%ld\n",maxnum);
  free(arrptr);
  return maxnum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can think of a much better algorithm that will do the job in O(n) instead of doing the same thing in O(n*n) what you are doing.

So the algorithm looks like this

1-initialize the array with size n+1 with all the 0's in it

2-for every query L, R, X increase array[L] by the value of X and decrease the value of array[R+1] by X

3-last step would be to get the prefix sum of the array which will give you the final processed array where you can find the maximum and return as an answer.

For eg.
5 3
arr=[0,0,0,0,0,0]

step 1:
1 2 100
arr=[100 0 -100 0 0 0]

step 2:
2 5 100
arr=[100 100 -100 0 0 -100]

step 3:
3 4 100
arr=[100 100 0 0 -100 -100]

step 4:
prefix sum
arr=[100 200 200 200 100 0] -> That's your final array and then you can easily return maximum from this array

Hope this helps! tell me if you can't understand anything I will be happy to help